# WSO2 Identity Server XACML PAP and Obligations

Tags: wso2, identity, xacml, pdp

When adding a set of obligations into an existing XACML Policy using the WSO2 XML Web Editor as described in the instructions for OASIS XACML Version 3 syntax,  the WSO2 editor throws the following error:

```
Entitlement policy is not updated. Error is :Invalid Entitlement Policy. Policy is not valid according to XACML schema
```

The following statements are placed right before the  tag at the end of the Policy definition, see the lines added:

Other, version 3 compliant syntax also throws the same error. Is there any further configuration required, some .xml or schema file adjustment, to make the editor recognize the Obligation statements as a valid syntax? This is WSO2 IS version 5.

**Update:**  Statement in error:

```
<Obligations>
  <Obligation ObligationId="send-email" FulfillOn="Deny">
    <AttributeAssignment AttributeId="email" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">myid@red.com</AttributeAssignment>
  </Obligation>
</Obligations>
```

**Update:** 
Below you find the working XACML V3 compliant policy after correcting the syntax of the Obligations statement:

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="RedLDAPPolicySaoPaulo" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" Version="1.0">
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Singapore</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:environment-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Permit-Rule1">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">123</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://w3.red.com/subject/employeeCountryCode" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ldap</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule"></Rule>
   <ObligationExpressions>
      <ObligationExpression FulfillOn="Permit" ObligationId="citycheck">
         <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">The validation passed successfully</AttributeValue>
         </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
      </ObligationExpression>
      <ObligationExpression FulfillOn="Deny" ObligationId="countrycheck">
         <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">The IDs country code is not valid</AttributeValue>
         </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
      </ObligationExpression>
   </ObligationExpressions>
</Policy>
```

Comment: Can you paste your entire policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the manual from OASIS XACML version 3, I found that the error was causes by missing syntax compliance. I've updated the statements to the latest specifications and my very simple example, as printed below, started to execute, adding an attribute with a comment string to the result.

Below a code example:

```
  <ObligationExpressions>
      <ObligationExpression FulfillOn="Permit" ObligationId="citycheck">
         <AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">The validation passed sucessfully</AttributeValue>
         </AttributeAssignmentExpression>
      </ObligationExpression>
   </ObligationExpressions>
```

Below the result copied from the WSO2 "Try It" console:

```
                     <Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
<Result>
<Decision>Permit</Decision>
<Status>
<StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
</Status>
<Obligations>
<Obligation ObligationId="citycheck">
<AttributeAssignment  AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
The validation passed successfully</AttributeAssignment>
</Obligation>
</Obligations>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ldap</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Result>
</Response>
```